# Magento 2 : How to show a menu in header part?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, header, topmenu

[image]I  want to show a menu in header part in magento 2? please help me how to add in header part?

Comment: Already menus are in header only?

Comment: This is only pic I set in home page same in show picture .how to show all menu ?

Comment: Whatever categories you have will be added in the menu by default Magento 2...

Comment: yes but I i have disply top of header luma logo and mini cart header part I show ?how to show

Comment: move the menu into header section in the /public_html/app/design/frontend/vendorname/Mytheme/Magento_Theme/layout<move element="navigation.sections" destination="header-wrapper" />

Comment: <move element="navigation.sections" destination="header-wrapper" />  set in defult file and how to set and admin panel side any chnages or any block create?

Comment: Also prathap i show header-wrapper

Comment: Pls Accept the answer if solved. @sannikalariya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**move the menu into header section in the**

> app/design/frontend/vendorname/Mytheme/Magento_Theme/layout

```
<move element="navigation.sections" destination="header-wrapper" />
```